# MySQL: Getting a 30-min intervals table from another one with several date fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three date fields (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS format): **in**, **out** and **near**. **in** and **out** always go together, while they might be along with **near** or not; **near** might exists by itself alone. There's no chance of all of them being `NULL`; something like this:

```
in_time             out_time            near_time
2019-10-02 10:46:31 2019-10-02 12:34:43 2019-10-02 09:51:57
NULL                NULL                2019-10-02 11:51:08
2019-10-02 12:02:40 2019-10-02 12:08:56 NULL
```

I need to turn it into another table with the sum of every date field grouped by 30-minute intervals, this way:

```
interval            qt_in qt_out qt_near
2019-10-02 08:30:00 1     0      2 
2019-10-02 09:00:00 1     1      5
2019-10-02 09:30:00 2     0      3
```

I mean, I need to know the amount of entries, leavings and "being arounds" per day and per 30-min periods within that day; any possible interval might have data, it doesn't mind it's [00:00 - 00:30], [12:00 - 12:30] or [23:30 - 24:00].

Right now I only have this:

```
SELECT
    from_unixtime((unix_timestamp(in_time) DIV (60 * 30)) * (30 * 60)) AS interval_in,
    sum(CASE WHEN in_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qt_in
    FROM count_config_module.ap_summary
    GROUP BY 
        interval_in
    ORDER BY 
        interval_in
        ;
```

Analogous queries for **out** and **near** return analogous results, but I'd need to mix all up in the same table with a unique and shared 30-min intervals field that might come from... some of them? All of them? Any of them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried a `UNION` between my three queries (erasing the `sum` line) in order to get that common field, but after that I cannot manage to do anything else (or at least anything useful) with it.

Comment: A possible solution from the Spanish version of SO, if anyone interested: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299849/mysql-obtener-tabla-con-intervalos-30minutales-a-partir-de-otra-con-fechas